# KendoGrid ServerSorting and ServerFiltering on child attributes or custom properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-open-access

I have a blocking issue on my serverside filtering and sorting of data.
My Kendo Grid sends requests to my C# backend.
This is what happens:

I fetch all Employee objects (I use Data Access)
An employee has a Person object, which contains person info like FirstName, LastName etc.
And it also has a GroupName
So my scheme is:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ID",
        fields: {
            FirstName: { type: "string", from: "Person.FirstName" },
            LastName: { type: "string", from: "Person.LastName" },
            GroupName: { type: "string" },
        }
    }
},
```

When I use a filter or sorting on the firstname or lastname, it wil try to filter the employee on attribute "Person.FirstName".
But the person is an addition to my DataAccess object, so it is not in the database.

When I use a filter or sorting on GroupName, it will also try to just filter on the groupname. But the groupname is filled in the backend and comes from EmployeeGroup.Name

So I am not able to filter serverside on any of these rows.
I would really love to know if there is any possibility to filter on custom attributes or childattributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change the Filtering values at the Controller end rename the filters as per the Names that are in the Database fetching logic.

Answer (score 0):

This nuget package could help you : https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinderEx

But what you need to do is create a ViewModel object which contains all properties you want, so

```
class EmployeeVMO
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  public string GroupName {get;set;}
}
```

You need AutoMapper to map this ViewModel object to you real database object. When these mappings are correctly applied, KendoGridBinderEx can be used which will automatically map Model to ViewModel (and back)

For some code example check this [source file](http://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx/blob/master/KendoGridBinderEx.Examples.MVC/Controllers/EmployeeController.cs).

See this live [example](http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/Employee).